# Finding the derivative of: $ y(x)=x⋅\sin(x)+x^2⋅\cos(3x) $

Tags: derivatives

I am a student and I have a problem in solving this derivative, so please help me.

 The problem:
    $$ y(x)=x⋅\sin(x)+x^2⋅\cos(3x)$$
I give this problem to online derivative calculator like derivative-calculator.net but the answer is not equal to my teacher answer.

online calc answer:
$$
y^\prime(x)=−3x2⋅\sin(3x)+2x⋅\cos(3x)+\sin(x)+x⋅\cos(x)
$$
teacher answer:
$$
y^\prime(x)  =  1⋅\sin(x)+x⋅\cos(x)+2x⋅\cos(3x)-3x^2⋅\sin(3x)
$$
what is the correct answer?
thanks.

Comment: How will you do this problem if the all online derivative calculators suddenly disappear ?

Comment: No this question should not be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are the same in different order since the first term of the first equation should be $$-3x^2\cdot \sin(3x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are actually correct. In fact, they are the same. For future reference use this online software:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+the+derivative+of+x%E2%8B%85sin%28x%29%2Bx%5E2%E2%8B%85cos%283x%29. But I hope you know how to use the product rule.